# Trying to remove first tr in table with JQuery

Tags: jquery, html-table

I have a table like this:

```
<div id="evttbldiv">
      <table id="eventtbl">
          <tr class="headers">
            <th>Evento</th>
            <th>Artista(s)</th>
            <th>Local</th>
            <th>Data</th>
            <th></th>
          </tr>
        <tr class="rowdata">
          <td class="lfm_event"></td>
          <td class="lfm_artists"></td>
          <td class="lfm_venue"></td>
          <td class="lfm_date"></td>
          <td><div class="arrow"></div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="rowinfo">
            <td colspan="5">
              hello
            </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
```

My JQuery:

```
container = $('#evttbldiv').html();
    console.log(container);
    $('.headers', container).remove();
    console.log(container);
```

What I'd like to do is remove the header row and place the rest (everything in between `<tr class="rowdata">` and the last `tr`in the `container` variable. However, it's not removing the headers in my JQuery, even with that line of code.

`console.log(container)` is displaying the same output in both instances.

Comment: `html()` returns a string, so you're assigning a string to `container` instead of a jQuery object. Why are you invoking `html()` in the first place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to use jQuery to affect the DOM of the item after you've converted it to HTML. Instead, `clone()` it, `remove()` the `.header`, and *then* convert it to HTML:

```
container = $('#evttbldiv').clone();
$('.headers', container).remove();
console.log(container);

// And if you need the HTML...
container_html = container.html();
console.log(container_html);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mstauffer/98XMj/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var $tds = $("#eventtbl .header th");

$("#eventtbl .header").remove()

// now append what is stored in $tds to whatever you want
$(".whateverYouWant").append($tds);
```

Comment: Sorry, i think i got the containers wrong... but what i mean is that you should try store ewhatever you want in a variable and append it to whatever you want

Answer (score 0):

Using chaining of jQuery methods you can create the fully modified table object  in one line and don't need to use `html()` method since you can append a jQuery object itself.

```
var $modifiedTable = $('#evttbldiv').clone().find('.headers').remove().end()

$('#someElement').append( $modifiedTable )
```

or convert to html string

```
console.log( $modifiedTable.html())
```